# Whirlpool washer won't fill unless settings are manipulated repeatedly

Tags: washer

This *may* be a duplicate, although I'm not sure which question it is duplicating. I have a Whirlpool washer with perfectly fine, clean, water supply and hoses. However, it often doesn't run water unless I continually switch the temperature or cycle load knobs back and forth. Is this a mechanical or electrical problem and is there any way I can adjust it?

Comment: What model is your washer?

Comment: Not sure. Says SM 8280867 on the inside. Inherited, so no clue about background info. Sorry,

Comment: Can you post a wiring diagram?

Comment: Sounds like a dirty switch contact or a sticking relay. Can't guess beyond that without digging out circuit diagram and applying a meter to the circuits. If it's under warranty, extended warranty, or the extended warranty built into some credit cards, call them and let them deal with it....

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. Unfortunately, I am not even certain where to start looking for the diagram you'e looking for (@ThreePhaseEel) and, as per warranty, nothing remains. It's a good 15 years old so... I'm worried it's probably just seen its time.